# What is the subject?

Tags: knowledge

Inspired by the recent "Name that Movie" puzzles, here is something similar.  I will be giving away too much information if I tell you the subject, so you will have to work that out yourself.  Once you get the first one, the rest should come easy.

Question 1

> Kim.com

Question 2

> A small apple

Question 3

> The Godfather is the key to his puppy's toy

Question 4

> http://www.google.com

Question 5

> Max's partner won 100m sprint for USA

Question 6

> An Italian PhD

Question 7

> Jerry's nemesis reading an eBook

Question 8

> What is the (specific) common theme?

**Hint:**

> They are not movies.

Comment: I thought of "Super Size Me" for "a small apple", since it described a man who was undergoing surgery to get his stomach shrunk down to that size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1** Kim.com

> Kim Dotcom is the founder of Mega and MegaUpload. He's the man who runs Mega. **Megaman**

**2** A small apple

> (with thanks to user2990472) **Little Mac**, from the Punch Out! games

**3** The Godfather is key to his puppy's toy

> The Godfather is the Don. A Kong is a type of dog toy. **Donkey Kong**

**4**http://www.google.com

> **Link**, central character of the Legend of Zelda series

**5** Max's partner won 100m sprint for USA

> Max's partner is *Sam* (Sam and Max video game series). They won a 100m sprint, so they *ran*. SamUSAran goes to **Samus Aran** of Metroid fame

**6** An Italian PhD

> A stretch, perhaps, but **Dr. Mario**?

**7** Jerry's nemesis reading an eBook

> Tom & Jerry, plus a Nook is an eBook reader. This gives **Tom Nook**, a character in Animal Crossing.

**8** The common theme

> Starting to think it's video game characters. All of them so far are characters who have appeared in Nintendo games. All are in the most recent Smash Bros. game, though Tom Nook appears only as a trophy/as stage dressing

Comment: Great job! I would've had no chance of getting this one. Is there a video game character Tom Kindle by any chance?

Comment: You're too good.  All of them is correct except Question 2 & 8.  Pink Lady is a type of apple, but what about 'small'?  And yes, Tom Nook is not in Super Smash Bros.

Comment: @rand al'thor, There is no video game character Tom Kindle.

Comment: @Eli Edited 2 and 8, for fear I was being too specific

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat Yep, they are all Nintendo characters.  They also share a common trait.

Comment: All of the characters are in a special group within Nintendo.  That's the group I'm looking for.

Comment: @Eli Actually Tom Nook made a few small appearances in Smash Bros.

Comment: Samus is of just Metroid fame; no Prime required. :)

Comment: They are characters in [Super Smash Bros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Smash_Bros.#Characters)

Comment: The common theme I was looking for was actually amiibo figurines. But @LogicianWithAHat's answer also fits, so I'll say it's the right answer. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

For Q#2

> little mac (small-little, apple-mac)

Comment: Sorry i cant comment to your answer yet so i have to make an answer on my own

Answer (score 3):

### Partial answer

Question 1

> Reference to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Dotcom); maybe the answer is **Kimble**?

Question 6

> I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottorato_di_ricerca), so maybe the answer is **dottorato** or **ricerca**? (Where's leoll2 when you need him?)

Question 7

> Jerry's nemesis is Tom in *Tom and Jerry*; another word for an ebook is a Kindle. So we get [Tom Kindle](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0454305/).